# Moving UIImagePickerController into a separate class

Tags: objective-c, class, uiimagepickercontroller

I've been trying to solve the same exact same problem as [this question](http://bit.ly/1Hj54qx) for a while, but am having trouble doing so. I've only been on XCode a few months, so help would be greatly appreciated.

In my parentVC.m I have this:

```
parentVC.m

- (IBAction)goToCamera:(id)sender {
     [_camera takePhoto];
     } return;
  }
```

This calls the takePhoto method in an equivalent of James's PhotoManager class: an NSObject Class called Camera - where I setup the UIImagePickerController. There I state the method in the header:

```
Camera.h

- (void) takePhoto;
```

then in the implementation:

```
Camera.m

@class ParentVC;
@interface Camera () <UIImagePickerControllerDelgate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) ParentVC *parentVC;
@end
@implementation Camera

-(void)takePhoto
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        cameraUI.delegate = self;
        [_parentVC presentViewController:cameraUI animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        DLog(@"camera wouldn't load");
        }
    }
@end
```

and no luck. I've tried many iterations and can't figure it out. Any ideas?